# Tier 2 Visa, baby born in UK, can it travel with a Canadian Passport?

Tags: visa

We are currently on a tier 2 Visa working in the UK, and our baby was born in the UK. We were wondering if, after the baby gets its Canadian citizenship and passport it can leave the country and come back on a visitor Visa (no longer than 6 months at a time). My wife plans to go to Canada at least twice a year to visit family, and if the baby doesn't overstay when it's in the UK, is there a reason it could be denied entry as a visitor? We would be getting private health insurance and care for the child, so that's not the issue, just crossing the border which we are curious about.

Comment: The UK's [public information page](https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-general/family-members) is not terribly helpful, but it implies that the answer to your question is *no:* "If you have children while you’re in the UK, you can apply for permission for them to stay.  You must do this if you want to travel in and out of the UK with your child."  Note the use of "must" in the second sentence.  However, there is no indication of how you would apply for that permission.

Comment: Indeed, as @phoog says, the guidance is so bad. But anyway, the [application website is here](https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/product/pbs-dependant-child)

Comment: It really is bad, but I just don't understand how they can stop someone travelling as a visitor? If my wife was not a tier 2 Visa holder, it would not be a problem if they did not overstay a visitor Visa (6 months), but because she has a tier 2 Visa, it's strange that it is actually more difficult to travel. Could it be possible that the guidance implies that the baby cant travel because it wouldn't have a valid passport, due to the fact it was born in the UK and without a visa and therefore it would not have a UK passport?

Comment: @MarkK I think it's basically because your baby can't travel by itself. If your wife is entering as a resident, the border force assumes there is a high likelihood of your baby overstaying, compounded by the fact that your baby wouldn't actually be punished for overstaying, so there's no disincentive for you not to do it.